# Animation continues after once trigged by scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a bar chart only with CSS and a animation from low to up that works well, however I want to run only when trigged by scroll.
Somehow the animation after trigged by the scroll does not stop, it keeps running.
look in the inspect element the latest bar.

jquery

```
// Bar Chart Animation
    function barChart(){
      $("#demographicsBars li .bar").each( function( key, bar ) {
        var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');

        $(this).animate({
          'height' : percentage + '%'
        }, 1000, function() {
            $('.viewerDemographics #demographicsBars li .bar').css('overflow','inherit');
         });
      });
    };

// Scroll Call Animation

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.viewerDemographics').each(function () {
            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
            var imageHeight = $(this).height();
            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (imagePos < topOfWindow + imageHeight && imagePos + imageHeight > topOfWindow) {

                barChart();

            } else {


            }
        });
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6r1vngh/)

Comment: What do you mean it keeps running? It runs once at the point where you asked it to trigger.

Comment: look in the inspect element the latest bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're asking it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/g6r1vngh/1/

Tell JS it hasn't been drawn

```
// Bar Chart Animation
var barChartDrawn = false;
```

Set it to true when it runs

```
function barChart(){
    barChartDrawn = true;
```

Don't do any of those calculations, or run the function, if it's true

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (barChartDrawn) return;
```